# Why does 'not continous' will lead to 'not holomorphic' for a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Why can't a function $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic if it isn't continous at at least one point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to answer this question is using Eric Towers' answer: holomorphic functions are differentiable, and differentiable functions are continuous, so if a function is not continuous, it is not holomorphic.

Another way is to prove it by definition. Take a point $a$ such that $f$ is not continuous in $a$.  Now take a sequence $z_n$ such that $\lim z_n=a$ and $|f(z_n)-f(a)|>\delta$ for some $\delta$ (such a sequence exists, because $f$ is not continuous at $a$.  Then, the limit
$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}$$
does not exist because $$\frac{|f(z)-f(a)|}{|z-a|} > \frac{\delta}{|z-a|}\to\infty $$ as $z\to a$.

Answer (score 6):

Holomorphic implies differentiable (at every point of its domain) implies continuous (at every point of its domain).